# how to add tags to article pages

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I'm new to Drupal. I accidentally deleted the Tag feature on our article page. Could someone explain how I can add it back to that page.

It also populated on a specific page.

Comment: Do you use Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

in Drupal 7

1. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields and add a new field named "Tags" with the type "Term reference" and the widget "  Autocomplete term widget (tagging)"
2. in the setting field page, configure it to reference the vocabulary named "Tags" (if the vocabulary doesn't exist, just add it in admin/structure/taxonomy/add)